# How to include out-of-limit measurements (such as negatives) in regressions

Tags: regression, censoring

I am trying to compare two diagnostic measurement techniques using Deming regression. Both of these techniques have their own lower limits of detection, and my data include both numeric values as well as non-numeric "negatives" that could not be given a numeric value because they are below the limit of detection. I can do regression using only samples that were positive according to both techniques, but I would like to include the "negatives" as well. Any idea of how can I include them in regression?

i.e.
test A has a lower detection limit of 0.5, while Test B's is 1.2

test A, test B

1.2, 1.5

3.5, 3.8

2.5, 2.9

1.6, 1.9

1.0, neg  << data point I want to include in regression

neg, neg << data point I want to include in regression

I tried giving "0" for the negatives but it would not be right as they can actually be anything under each technique's own lower limit of detection.

Comment: 1) It sounds like you're using the term "negative" to refer to values that are below threshold, even if the values themselves are not negative numbers. Is that right? 2) What exactly is the regression problem? E.g. are you regressing test B results against test A results? Or, are you regressing each against some other set of variables? 3) To confirm--the lower detection limits are known, right?

Comment: 1) yes negatives are below threshold but I do not have the numerical values, I only know that they are negatives. 2) I want to regress B against A. I want to use deming regression if possible. 3) yes, lower detection limits are known. thank you!